# Mindblowing jQuery Weirdness

Tags: jquery

...at least to me. This code *used* to work fine. I'm pretty sure nothing has changed, but now all of the sudden it behaves oddly. Basically I'm trying to create inline editing functionality. When the user clicks on the link, it dynamically generates a textbox and a confirm and cancel link. I'm having problems with the cancel link not removing everything in the cell.

HTML:

```
...
<td class="bid">
   <a href="javascript:" class="102093" title="Click to modify bid">$0.45</a>
</td>
...
```

Binding jQuery (in `$(function())`):

```
$('.bid a').live('click', renderBidChange);
....
$('.report_table .cancel').live('click', cancelUpdate);
```

`renderBidChange` (this function creates the dynamic elements):

```
function renderBidChange(){
    var cpc = $(this);
    var value = cpc.text().replace('$', '');
    var cell = cpc.parent('.bid');
    cpc.hide();

    var input = document.createElement('input');
    $(input).attr({type:'text',class:'dynamic cpc-input'}).val(value);
    cell.append(input);

    var accept = document.createElement('a');
    $(accept).addClass('accept').attr({'href':'javascript:',
      'title':'Accept Changes'}).text('Accept Changes');
    cell.append(accept);

    var cancel = document.createElement('a');
    $(cancel).addClass('cancel').attr({'href':'javascript:',
      'title':'Cancel Changes'}).text('Cancel Changes');
    cell.append(cancel);

    $(input).focus();
    input.select();
}
```

`cancelUpdate` this function just removes everything visible (all the dynamic junk in this case) in the cell and shows what used to be there.

```
function cancelUpdate(){
    var cell = $(this).parent();
    cell.find(':visible').remove();
    cell.find(':hidden').show();
}
```

However, for some reason, the cancel link remains after it is clicked! Everything else is removed except that. W T F

Thanks for any insight you're able to provide! I'm sure it's just some stupid little detail I'm over[caffeinatedly]looking...

**UPDATE** Immediately after posting this I epiphanied that it may be a CSS issue, but after double checking my code, it is not.

Comment: I'm not sure what's worse - the fact that this question is tagged "weird", or that "weird" is already an established tag with several questions using it.

Comment: haha... but it IS weird! i guess once you've worked within a framework for long enough and know what to expect, you're allowed to start marking oddities as weird :)

Comment: That is weird. I would council first to swap the accept and cancel buttons to make sure it's not a "last element" issue, but reading through the code I would expect the cancel to get removed same as you. Can I also council "sleep on it, look again tomorrow"?

Comment: I've run into some weird quirks with .live(). What happens when you bind the handler to the cancel element directly when you create it?

Also, waaaay off topic, but @drachenstern s/council/counsel/g ;)

Comment: hehehe, thanks kibibu, time for me to take my own advice, dev env shut down, server apps spooled down for the night, time to log off ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a slight tweak here:

```
$('.bid a:not(.cancel)').live('click', renderBidChange);
```

Since you've moved to `.live()`, the first function is also running with a click on cancel :)

Comment: this is correct. how this has not been an issue until now is beyond me, but thanks for being my spare eyes! :)

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you change:

```
$('.report_table .cancel').live('click', cancelUpdate);
```

to

```
$('.bid .cancel').live('click', cancelUpdate);
```

I don't expect a solution, but I'm just doublechecking

What's the "live" function for .accept? Does it work (presumably so)

Comment: thanks for looking into this. nick's answer is correct! i was binding ALL my links, not just the initial one.

Comment: yeah his posted moments after I submitted mine, I read his and "/facepalm" ... yay it works!